# Знаки препинания в предложении с разными видами связи

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки препинания. Предложение из заданий ЕГЭ по р.я.(укажите цифры, на месте которых должна стоять запятая)
Рассказывают (1) что (2) когда Петр Первый не знал (3) где взять ему медь для отливки новых орудий в период войны со шведами (4) некий пушечный мастер посоветовал ему снять с колоколен половину колоколов (5) и что именно благодаря этому русская армия смогла победить шведов в ряде сражений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1Рассказывают], (2 что, (3 когда Петр Первый не знал), (4 где взять ему медь для отливки новых орудий в период войны со шведами),2 некий пушечный мастер посоветовал ему снять с колоколен половину колоколов) и (5 что именно благодаря этому русская армия смогла победить шведов в ряде сражений).
1. Главное предложение; 2,5 - однородные придаточные, связанные одиночным союзом и; 3 - обстоятельственное придаточное времени, 4 - придаточное изъяснительное.

Answer (score 0):

1. Запятая на стыке союзов ставится, если после первого союза следует одиночный союз в придаточной части: Но в этом болоте невозможно было долго стоять, потому что, когда в первые морозы оно покрылось слоем льда, вода подо льдом понизилась, и так образовался лед-тощак (Пришв.).
2. Если после первого союза следует двойной союз, то запятая на стыке союзов не ставится. Это случается, когда подчинительный союз имеет в главной части предложения слово то: Прокофьев, одеваясь на ощупь в кромешной темноте, говорил, что писательство — самое тяжелое и заманчивое занятие в мире и что если бы он не был геологом, то наверняка бы сделался писателем (Пауст.) (В. В Лопатин)

Answer (score -1):

Между ЧТО и КОГДА запятая не нужна, так как она не ставится на стыке двух союзов. Запятые будут расставлены так: 1,3,4,5.

Comment: 2. Если после первого союза следует двойной союз, то запятая на стыке союзов не ставится. Это случается, когда подчинительный союз имеет в главной части предложения слово то: Прокофьев, одеваясь на  
ощупь в кромешной темноте, говорил, что писательство — самое тяжелое и заманчивое занятие в мире и что если бы он не был геологом, то наверняка бы сделался писателем (Пауст.) 
(В. В. Лопатин)

Comment: согласна с Вами, спасибо

Comment: @Cтася Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.